# requirejs + django_select2

Tags: django, requirejs, jquery-select2, wagtail

I'm building a wagtail / django app using requirejs as js assets combiner, for the site front end.

I'm using it because I've ever been in a kind of JS dependencies hell, where nothing works because of multiple versions of same libs loaded, from different django apps... (I don't even know if it is a good solution)

I've to tell that I'm not a JS expert, and I've none arround me :(
I'm using the good old templates to render the pages, not using angular, react, riot nor vue : I'm a pretty old school dev :)

I've already adapted some scripts to use require, but I'm stuck for now...

I've installed the django_select2 application, and I'm trying to adapt the django_select2.js asset.

I've loaded select2 through bower, and I've updaetd my config.js:

```
"shim": {
    select2: {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "$.fn.select2"
    }
}, 
paths: {
    ...
    select2: "select2/dist/js/select2"
}
```

Then I'm trying to adapt the django_select2.js:

```
require(['jquery', 'select2'], function ($, select2) {
   return (function ($) {
        var init = function ($element, options) {
            $element.select2(options);
        };

        var initHeavy = function ($element, options) {
            var settings = $.extend({
                ajax: {
                    data: function (params) {
                        var result = {
                            term: params.term,
                            page: params.page,
                            field_id: $element.data('field_id')
                        }

                        var dependentFields = $element.data('select2-dependent-fields')
                        if (dependentFields) {
                            dependentFields = dependentFields.trim().split(/\s+/)
                            $.each(dependentFields, function (i, dependentField) {
                                result[dependentField] = $('[name=' + dependentField + ']', $element.closest('form')).val()
                            })
                        }

                        return result
                    },
                    processResults: function (data, page) {
                        return {
                            results: data.results,
                            pagination: {
                                more: data.more
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, options);

            $element.select2(settings);
        };

        $.fn.djangoSelect2 = function (options) {
            var settings = $.extend({}, options);
            $.each(this, function (i, element) {
                var $element = $(element);
                if ($element.hasClass('django-select2-heavy')) {
                    initHeavy($element, settings);
                } else {
                    init($element, settings);
                }
            });
            return this;
        };

        $(function () {
            $('.django-select2').djangoSelect2();
        });
    }($));
});
```

I'm having a **Mismatched anonymous define()** when running my page in the browser...

I'me realy not a JS expert, I'm coding by trial and error... Could anyone help me with this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have an auto-response...

I've inherited the mixin:

```
class _Select2Mixin(Select2Mixin):
    def _get_media(self):
        """
        Construct Media as a dynamic property.

        .. Note:: For more information visit
            https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/media/#media-as-a-dynamic-property
        """
        return forms.Media(js=('django_select2/django_select2.js', ),
                           css={'screen': (settings.SELECT2_CSS,)})

    media = property(_get_media)


class _Select2MultipleWidget(_Select2Mixin, forms.SelectMultiple):
    pass
```

Then I can use the widget:

```
    class DocumentationSearchForm(forms.Form):
        ...
        document_domains = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False,
                                                      label=_('Document domains'),
                                                      queryset=NotImplemented,
                                                      widget=_Select2MultipleWidget)
```

I've set my `config.js` file for path:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery/dist/jquery',
        select2: "select2/dist/js"
    }, 
    shim: {
        "select2/select2": {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "$.fn.select2"
        }
    }
});
```

Then I've overridden the django_select2.js file, to wrap the content in a require satement:

```
require(['jquery', 'select2/select2'], function ($) {
   (function ($) {
        var init = function ($element, options) {
            $element.select2(options);
        };

        var initHeavy = function ($element, options) {
            var settings = $.extend({
                ajax: {
                    data: function (params) {
                        var result = {
                            term: params.term,
                            page: params.page,
                            field_id: $element.data('field_id')
                        }

                        var dependentFields = $element.data('select2-dependent-fields')
                        if (dependentFields) {
                            dependentFields = dependentFields.trim().split(/\s+/)
                            $.each(dependentFields, function (i, dependentField) {
                                result[dependentField] = $('[name=' + dependentField + ']', $element.closest('form')).val()
                            })
                        }

                        return result
                    },
                    processResults: function (data, page) {
                        return {
                            results: data.results,
                            pagination: {
                                more: data.more
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, options);

            $element.select2(settings);
        };

        $.fn.djangoSelect2 = function (options) {
            var settings = $.extend({}, options);
            $.each(this, function (i, element) {
                var $element = $(element);
                if ($element.hasClass('django-select2-heavy')) {
                    initHeavy($element, settings);
                } else {
                    init($element, settings);
                }
            });
            return this;
        };

        $(function () {
            $('.django-select2').djangoSelect2();
        });
    }($));
});
```

That's all, folks !